# ERROR: Event qualifications are not implemented for rules on SELECT

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, rules

I'm trying to implement a view-level rule to limit available columns to a selection for certain "web_anonymous" user for postgrest api.
Example on an events view, I don't want the whole view to be available for this group and therefore limit it to certain columns.

There is my code

```
    ON SELECT TO manifestation.ds_evenements
    WHERE (CURRENT_USER = 'web_anonyme')
    DO INSTEAD
(SELECT nom_evenement, description_evenement
FROM manifestation.ds_evenements);
```

When I want to validate the rule I have this error message that I cannot interpret:

```
ERROR: Event qualifications are not implemented for rules on SELECT
```

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an `ON SELECT` rule with a `WHERE` condition. Moreover, your rule is cyclical.

Don't try to use a rule for that. Instead, define the view so that it does the right thing, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW ... AS
SELECT /* something */
WHERE current_user IS DISTINCT FROM 'web_anonyme'
UNION ALL
SELECT /* something else */
WHERE current_user = 'web_anonyme';
```

An alternative might be using row level security on the underlying tables in combination with a `security_invoker` view.